# Show that the following algorithm to solve a system of equations works:

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I came across the following exercise in preparation of an Exam. And I solved it as far and as good as I could at this point, and would appreciate it, if somebody could point out, and correct my mistake, since I have no reference points. Thank you.

**The Exercise**

Let $\mathbf{A} = (a_{ij})$ be a regular $n \times n$ matrix of which we know the $\mathbf{LU}-factorisation$. We want to solve a system $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ wherein $\mathbf{\tilde{A}} = (\tilde{a}_{ij})$ differs from $\mathbf{A}$ only on the position $(1,1)$. We know that $\tilde{a}_{11} = a_{11}+ \alpha$ and that $\tilde{a}_{ij} = a_{ij}, \forall (i,j) \neq (1,1)$. Let $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}$ also be a regular matrix.
We have now the following algorithm to solve $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$:

1. solve $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}= \alpha \vec{e}_1$ in $\vec{z}$. with $ \vec{z}= [z_1,z_2,...,z_n]^T$ and $ \vec{e}_1= [1,0,...,0]^T$
2. solve $\mathbf{A}\vec{y}= \vec{b}$ in $\vec{y}$, with $ \vec{y}= [y_1,y_2,...,y_n]^T$.
3. compute $\vec{x}= \vec{y}-\frac{y_1}{1+z_1}\vec{z}$

(a) show that this algorithm solves the system $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$.

(b) if we use the known $\mathbf{LU}$-decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$, what would be the order of computations (multiplications and additions) to solve $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$? And what would it be if we didn't know the $\mathbf{LU}$-decomposition?

(c) change the algorithm in such a fashion, that it would solve the same system, if $\mathbf{\tilde{A}}$ would differ from $\mathbf{A}$ not in $(1,1)$ but in $(i,j)$. Show that the new algorithm gives back the solution of that system.

**What I came up with**

(a)*Proof:* We know that $\vec{z} = \alpha \mathbf{A}^{-1}\vec{e}_1$ and therefore is $z_1 = \alpha(\mathbf{A}^{-1})_{1,1} \iff 1+ z_1 = 1+\alpha(\mathbf{A}^{-1})_{1,1} \iff  1- \frac{1}{(1+z_1)}-\frac{1}{(1+z_1)}\alpha(\mathbf{A}^{-1})_{1,1}= \vec{0}$

Define $\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}:=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 0 &... & 0 \\ \vdots &\vdots &  \ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&...&0\\\end{bmatrix}$ then we have that the expression above is equivalent with $$\vec{e}_1  - \frac{1}{(1+z_1)}\vec{e}_1-\frac{1}{(1+z_1)}\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\vec{e}_1= \vec{0}$$
$$\iff \alpha y_1 \vec{e}_1 - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}\alpha \vec{e}_1 -\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\alpha\vec{e}_1= \vec{0}$$
$$\iff \vec{b}+\alpha y_1 \vec{e}_1 - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}\alpha \vec{e}_1 -\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\alpha\vec{e}_1= \vec{b}$$
$$\iff \mathbf{A}\vec{y}+\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}\vec{y} - (\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}_{\alpha})(\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}(\mathbf{A}^{-1}\alpha \vec{e}_1)) = \vec{b}$$
$$\iff \mathbf{A}\vec{y}+\mathbf{A}_{\alpha}\vec{y} - (\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}_{\alpha})(\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}(\vec{z})) = \vec{b}$$

and because now  $ (\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}_\alpha)=\mathbf{\tilde{A}}$ we get:

$$\iff \mathbf{\tilde{A}}\vec{y} - \mathbf{\tilde{A}}(\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}(\vec{z})) = \vec{b}$$
$$\iff \mathbf{\tilde{A}}(\vec{y} -\frac{y_1}{(1+z_1)}(\vec{z})) = \vec{b}$$
And because of step 3) we conclude that
$$\iff \mathbf{\tilde{A}}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$$ QED

(b) I came up with $(2n^2 +n +1)(\times and +)$, can this be correct?

(c) I came up with the following algorithm, but wouldn't know how to verify it:

1. solve $\mathbf{A}\vec{z}=\alpha\vec{e}_i$ in $\vec{z}$
2. solve $\mathbf{A}\vec{y}=\vec{b}_i$ in $\vec{y}$
3. compute $\vec{x} = \vec{y}-\frac{y_j}{1+z_j}\vec{z}$

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If your course covers [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), you can use it with $u=\alpha e_1$ and $v=e_1$ instead of reinventing the proof for this special case, and decompose the formula for the inverse into the three steps.